# How do I determine the standard deviation of multiple categories within the same column in R

Tags: r

I have two columns, 'Name' and 'Price'. I'd like to determine the standard deviation of the prices for each group/category of the column 'Name'. These columns are in the form of a data frame in R.

```
                   Name    Price
1               Llandudno 21700000
2               Llandudno 15500000
3               Llandudno  9800000
4                Hout Bay  2995000
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a data.frame named df. Here is a base R method using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Price ~ Suburb, data=df, FUN=sd)
```

This creates a data.frame that has the standard deviations by name.

---

The equivalent of `aggregate` using the `data.table` package, would be as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, list("Name"=sd(Price)), by=.(Suburb)]
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Suburb    Price
Llandudno 21700000
                 Llandudno 15500000
                 Llandudno  9800000
                 Hout_Bay  2995000
                 Hout_Bay  3995000")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   summarise(new = sd(Price))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

#     Suburb     new
#      (chr)   (dbl)
#1  Hout Bay     NaN
#2 Llandudno 5951750
```

Note that 'Hout Bay' gives NaN which is expected since you only have one value

Comment: This is the first time that I've been exposed to pipe operators. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Richard No problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sqldf`.  The advantage is that we don't need to translate the code if we work on `sql` as well.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT Suburb, stdev(Price) AS SDPrice
       FROM df1
       GROUP BY Suburb")
#     Suburb   Price
#1  Hout Bay       0
#2 Llandudno 5951750
```

Comment: How fast is this method?

Comment: @MaratTalipov If we are working on  huge database, using `sql` commands on the database would be quicker than reading it in R.  But, if it is a small dataset, sql commands in R would be slower.

Comment: The data set is not large at all unfortunately. 'sqldf' is great nonetheless. I appreciate it.